# Crossfading audio at beginning and ending of video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

The html5 video tag has a loop attribute. When playing a video in a continuous loop, it doesn't do this seamlessly. I hear cracks and pops at the beginning. With ffmpeg I am able to trim `.05` seconds from the start and end to make audio and video uniform. That helped a lot but still not fully smooth when played in a loop. Then crossfade came into question. How can I gradually lower the volume at the end of video and gradually raise the volume at the beginning?

ffmpeg `.05` seconds from the start and end

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    duration=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//)
    length=$(echo "$duration" | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + A[3] }' )
    trim_start=.05
    trim_end=$(echo "$length" - .05 - "$trim_start" | bc)
    echo ffmpeg -ss "$trim_start" -i "$f" -c copy -map 0 -t "$trim_end" "${f%.mp4}-trimmed.mp4"
done
```

Comment: Why are you not just using [`ffprobe` to get the duration](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/15562/1760)?

Comment: @LordNeckBeard, yes I will change it to ffprobe for duration. However is there a way to decrease audio in the last 30 frames or second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For purposes of this answer I'll assume the audio is encoded with an aac codec.

For each video:

Use *ffmpeg* to extract the sound track to its own file.

```
ffmpeg -i "${f%.mp4}" -vn -acodec copy "${f%-sound.aac}"
```

If not yet known, determine the duration of the audio file.  In some cases ffmpeg is known to give an incorrect duration (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437750/how-to-get-the-real-actual-duration-of-an-mp3-file-vbr-or-cbr-server-side), so I'd use *sox*.

```
duration=$(sox soundtrack_before_processing.mp3 -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p')
```

Use *sox* to apply fades in and out.

```
sox "${f%-sound.aac}" "${f%-sound-with-fades.aac}" fade t $fade_in_seconds $duration $fade_out_seconds
```

Replace the audio track in the original video file with the faded track.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${f%.mp4}" -i "${f%-sound-with-fades.aac}" -map 0:v -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict experimental -shortest "${%f-new.mp4}"
```

Comment: Why you are using sox when same can be done with ffmpeg?

Comment: I was using sox rather than ffmpeg because of the SO question listed in the answer, which notes an issue with ffmpeg related to getting the actual duration of an audio stream.  Granted, that may be dependent upon which code was used to encode the stream.